# Why does BitmapImage.CacheOption impact where image can be loaded from?

Tags: c#, wpf, filenotfoundexception

I'm creating a `BitmapImage` as follows:

```
bitmapImage.BeginInit();
bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(resourceName, UriKind.Relative);
bitmapImage.EndInit();
```

If I use this code (with the default CacheOption), then the image (PNG) loads fine whether the image has a Build Action of Resource or if it is marked as "Copy to Output Directory".

However, if I set the `CacheOption` to `OnLoad` as follows...

```
bitmapImage.BeginInit();
bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(resourceName, UriKind.Relative);
bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bitmapImage.EndInit();
```

... then it will not load from Resource - only from file (Copy to Output Directory).  If I try to load from resource I get an exception explicitly saying that it must load from file:

> FileNotFoundException was unhandled
>
> Could not find file 'C:\Users\Victor\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AddingForJack\AddingForJack\bin\Debug\Images\robot.png'.

My understanding about `CacheOption` is simply when the image is loaded - that it impacts the presence of the image memory.  Why does this also impact where the image can be loaded from?

Comment: set breakpoint after   `bitmapImage.UriSource` and show what in `bitmapImage.UriSource`. And show what in `resourceName`.

Comment: You should not rely on `UriKind.Relative` when you want to load an image resource. Use a [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) instead. In order to find out what exactly happens in your example, you will have to take a look at the framework sources. You may get e.g. JetBrains dotPeek and inspect PresentationCore.dll.